# JQuery Tooltip Plugin from Jorn

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml, jquery-plugins

I am thinking someone may have run across this one, but not sure.  From a high level, I am trying to roll over a input [type=text] and display a tool tip (with the contained value) using the plugin available at [http://bassitance.de](http://bassistance.de).

I have to use titles and classes for validation on the specific elements, so I put a blank div to hold the input [type=text] value for the roll over.

Issue:

It won't hold the value of 2 text boxes at once.  Once I put a value in the box on the right, the tooltip on the left goes away.  Same thing if I switch it aroun.  I can't keep a tooltip on more than one element.

Here is the code (Note: You will have to download the plugins in the source as I am not sure where the live versions are if there are any).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/scripts/jquery-tooltip/jquery.tooltip.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-tooltip/jquery.tooltip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("input").change(function(){
            var newTitle = $(this).val();
            $(this).parent().attr("title",newTitle);
            // re-init tool tip
            reload();
        });

        // Init tooltip
        reload();
    });

    reload = function(){
        $("div").tooltip();
    }
</script>
<body>
    <table border="1px solid black">
        <tr>
            <td title="hello">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" value=""/>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" value=""/>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="debug"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, I ended up hacking into this too much.  I ended up going with a different plugin that allowed me to assign the value off of something other than the title, i.e. the current value in the textbox to avoid the need to scroll.

Comment: Here is the site I got the tool tip that carried out my function properly.

http://www.walterzorn.com/tooltip/tooltip_e.htm

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your question. Do you want to show two tooltips at once or your problem is that the title attribute you set on each reload function erases both titles?

I used this plugin before if you explain more, or show a demo of your example i would be able to help.

Sinan.

**EDIT** Working version: (It changes titles of 'td's)

```
$(function(){
    $("input").change(function(){
            var newTitle = $(this).val();
            $(this).parent().parent('td').attr("title",newTitle);
            // re-init tool tip
            reload();
    });

    // Init tooltip
    reload();
});

reload = function(){
    $("[title]").tooltip();
}
```

Comment: I am only trying to show the updated tooltip when you roll over the specified element.  Only one tooltip stays active though.  It is the tooltip on the most recently changed box.